# setsyscolors COLOR_3DLIGHT but only for dialogs and exclude buttons? Is this possible?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, user32, systemcolors

COLOR_3DLIGHT - Light color for three-dimensional display elements (for edges facing the light source.) but this includes both dialogs and buttons.

Problem is that I want buttons to be excluded.

Unfortunately something like color_btnlight does not exist.
Basically i want to use SetSysColors only for dialogs(system wide), and not for buttons too. Is there any way to achieve that separation ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  (SetSysColors function)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (GetSysColor function)